# custom jquery animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am working on a custom project where I need to slide in/out div on click of menus.

Please check the link where I am working http://ahmedabadwebs.com/birds/index.php click on menus (about, concept, contact).

You may view the source code of page for js and code.

The problem is when I click first time on any of the about, concept or contact menu the div/box moves in from right side, this is fine. but after that when i click on other menus they don't come in alike.

What I want to do is when we click on about the about div should come and stop in middle of page, then we click on other menu say concept, then the about div should move out slowing to left side and concept div should move in from the left side.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: provide relevant code here, PLEASE!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to reset the `pagei` variable, and also clear the interval once it is complete.

See [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval)

Comment: thanks i solved the problem by reseting pagei = 0